# remotely change permissions on windows share using php

Tags: php, permissions, windows-share

I need to change permissions on different remote windows shares for a central user management. While there are several projects handling the samba connection and filesystem CRUD part, I did not find any projects handling permissions.

I do not have the possibility to run the PHP-Skript on Windows - it has to run under linux. The remote shares are on windows 2003 and 2008 servers.

Any hints for projects are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to control the ACLs from a AD domain?

Comment: Yes - for example, I'd like to add a user to the ACL for a share and set the write and read permission.

Comment: You might want to look at this: http://adldap.sourceforge.net/  Modifying active directory is a pain unless you're on Windows.  You can script it via PowerShell...

Comment: My focus is on windows shares and not user/group-management - I already got the latter working in different projects. however, I'm stuck with the permission settings for windows shares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in essence, there is no framework in PHP having the needed features. I'll have to switch to another language to perform the operations or being stuck on a windows version of php.